# RecyclerView item. Get data from multiple sources

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room

I`ve made an app that uses RecyclerViev and gets data from DB using ROOM.

Previously All the data that was needed to form a Row Item was located within a single class. For example, "User.class" had fields "name" "lastName". And of course i have List of User objects for my RecyclerView adapter. Also I made database, using ROOM to store my data.

Now i want to expand my app. Every RecyclerView row should display not only Name and Last Name of user, but for example 3 last "Orders" for that user. So I made new "Order" class with some fields and annotated it properly for ROOM database and made some constrains using @ForeignKey"

Now i have one RecyclerView, one RecyclerView adapter, single layout for custom row, and TWO classes (two db tables also) with data. What is the proper way to form an Object that will be displayed in the RecyclerView, that have data from users db and from orders db?

Comment: so do you remember how did you solve this back in the days ? because I have a similar issue now - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69289074/recyclerview-adapter-depends-on-two-sources-of-data

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just create a new class which will contain all the properties you need to use in the RecyclerView Adapter and use this class in it. Also, there is no need to save the new entity into the DB.

Another approach is just to use both sources of information without creating a new POJO as I suggested above. Just pass all the User and Order info to your adapter and extract the needed info from each source.

I personally prefer the first approach. Also, there are probably better approaches out there, so you can investigate a little bit more.

Comment: is the first approach a realization of MVVM the pattern?

Comment: No, it's not. It's just a way of constructing the required data. Of course, you can easily integrate it into the MVVM pattern.

Comment: I dont need "easy and working" approach. I need "BEST PRACTICE approach accepted by google top coders" lol. What your thoughts about this situation?

Comment: Sadly, am I not a Google top developer my friend. If you want you can reach out to Jake Wharton, Rebecca Franks, Cyril Mottier and many others who ARE Android GDEs. 
The solution I proposed, does not give you a full-blown integration of this simple data construction process into the MVVM patter. You can have your activity listening for updates from the ViewModel and before broadcasting the new updates you can construct your data in the suggested way in your ViewModel or in a separated class with some specific responsibilities (I am not familiar with your architecture).