# RecyclerView Adapter depends on two sources of data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room

Assume that

- I have a user with multiple accounts.
- Each account might have multiple pages that they control.
- pages could be controlled by one or more accounts.
- all this data is stored in Room Database with entities {**UserEntity**,**PageEntity**,**User_Page_Entity**}, where **User_Page_Entity** control the relation between users and their pages by storing only their primary key ids.

My Recycler View is supposed to show all the pages, where some of this pages are controlled by the current logged in user where an item of my Recycler View look like this :
[image: Recycler View Item]
where the red/green circle indicate whether this page belongs to the current logged in user or not.

My problem is my Recycler View depends on two sources of data :

1. `LiveData<List<PageEntity>>` that shows all the pages stored in database.
2. `LiveData<List<User_Page_Entity>>` that indicates which of this pages is controlled by the current user.

Since Room launches a notifier to all of its observers at the same time whenever there's a change in the database, if I initialized an observer on both sources and whenever they changed launch a `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter, it results in two `notifyDataSetChanged` called at the same time raising an exception that one of the holders that were detached in one of two method calls, is asking to be detached again.

```
IllegalArgumentException: called detach on an already detached child ViewHolder
```

In contrast I can't call `notifyDataSetChanged` on only one observer since I don't know which one would be called first by Room.

Now I don't know what to do and how to maintain the relation between these two data sources in the same recycler view, after two days of thinking I'm totally willing to hear any suggestion or advice and implement it to make the application as clean coded as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer to this question lies in my other related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69292367/10485156) and its [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69321758/10485156)

of course until someone offers another good solution, I'm still open to suggestions but I wanted to post what I did to solve my problems in case someone saw my questions in future.

Comment: Your solution of combining the sources in a single `LiveData` is the correct one.